# Mock/test basic http.get request

Tags: go

I am leaning to write unit tests and I was wondering the correct way to unit test a basic `http.get` request.

I found an API online that returns fake data and wrote a basic program that gets some user data and prints out an ID:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type UserData struct {
    Meta interface{} `json:"meta"`
    Data struct {
        ID     int    `json:"id"`
        Name   string `json:"name"`
        Email  string `json:"email"`
        Gender string `json:"gender"`
        Status string `json:"status"`
    } `json:"data"`
}

func main() {
    resp := sendRequest()
    body := readBody(resp)
    id := unmarshallData(body)
    fmt.Println(id)
}

func  sendRequest() *http.Response {
    resp, err := http.Get("https://gorest.co.in/public/v1/users/1841")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    return resp
}

func readBody(resp *http.Response) []byte {
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    return body
}

func unmarshallData(body []byte) int {
    var userData UserData
    json.Unmarshal(body, &userData)
    return userData.Data.ID
}
```

This works and prints out 1841. I then wanted to write some tests that validate that the code is behaving as expected, e.g. that it correctly fails if an error is returned, that the data returned can be unmarshalled. I have been reading online and looking at examples but they are all far more complex that what I feel I am trying to achieve.

I have started with the following test that ensures that the data passed to the `unmarshallData` function can be unmarshalled:

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

func Test_unmarshallData(t *testing.T) {
    type args struct {
        body []byte
    }
    tests := []struct {
        name string
        args args
        want int
    }{
        {name: "Unmarshall", args: struct{ body []byte }{body: []byte("{\"meta\":null,\"data\":{\"id\":1841,\"name\":\"Piya\",\"email\":\"priya@gmai.com\",\"gender\":\"female\",\"status\":\"active\"}}")}, want: 1841},
    }
        for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            if got := unmarshallData(tt.args.body); got != tt.want {
                t.Errorf("unmarshallData() = %v, want %v", got, tt.want)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Any advise on where to go from here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before moving on to the testing, your code has a serious flow, which will become a problem if you don't take care about it in your future programming tasks.

https://pkg.go.dev/net/http See the second example

> The client must close the response body when finished with it

Let's fix that now (we will have to come back on this subject later), two possibilities.

1/ within `main`, use defer to Close that resource after you have drained it;

```golang
func main() {
    resp := sendRequest()
    defer body.Close()
    body := readBody(resp)
    id := unmarshallData(body)
    fmt.Println(id)
}
```

2/ Do that within `readBody`

```golang
func readBody(resp *http.Response) []byte {
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    return body
}
```

Using a [defer](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#defer) is the expected manner to close the resource. It helps the reader to identify the lifetime span of the resource and improve readability.

Notes : I will not be using much of the [table test driven pattern](https://dave.cheney.net/2019/05/07/prefer-table-driven-tests), but you should, like you did in your OP.

Moving on to the testing part.

Tests can be written under the same package or its fellow version with a trailing `_test`, such as `[package target]_test`. This has implications in two ways.

- Using a separate package, they will be ignored in the final build. Which will help to produce smaller binaries.
- Using a separate package, you test the API in a black box manner, you can access only the identifiers it explicitly exposes.

Your current tests are white boxed, meaning you can access any declaration of `main`, public or not.

About `sendRequest`, writing a test around this is not very interesting because it does too little, and your tests should not be written to test the std library.

But for the sake of the demonstration, and for good reasons we might want to not rely on external resources to execute our tests.

In order to achieve that we must make the global dependencies consumed within it, an injected dependency. So that later on, it is possible to replace the one thing it depends on to react, the [http.Get](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Get) method.

```golang
func  sendRequest(client interface{Get() (*http.Response, error)}) *http.Response {
    resp, err := client.Get("https://gorest.co.in/public/v1/users/1841")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    return resp
}
```

Here i use an inlined interface declaration `interface{Get() (*http.Response, error)}`.

Now we can add a new test which injects a piece of code that will return exactly the values that will trigger the behavior we want to test within our code.

```golang
type fakeGetter struct {
    resp *http.Response
    err  error
}

func (f fakeGetter) Get(u string) (*http.Response, error) {
    return f.resp, f.err
}
func TestSendRequestReturnsNilResponseOnError(t *testing.T) {

    c := fakeGetter{
        err: fmt.Errorf("whatever error will do"),
    }

    resp := sendRequest(c)
    if resp != nil {
        t.Fatal("it should return a nil response when an error arises")
    }
}
```

Now run this test and see the result. It is not conclusive because your function contains a call to [log.Fatal](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.16.7:src/log/log.go;l=333), which in turns executes an [os.Exit](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Exit); We cannot test that.

If we try to change that, we might think we might call for [panic](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#panic) instead because we can [recover](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#recover).

I don't recommend doing that, in my opinion, this is smelly and bad, but it exists, so we might consider. This is also the least possible change to the function signature. Returning an error would break even more the current signatures. I want to minimize this for that demonstration. But, as a rule of thumb, **return an error and always check them**.

In the `sendRequest` function, replace this call `log.Fatalln(err)` with `panic(err)` and update the test to capture the panic.

```golang
func TestSendRequestReturnsNilResponseOnError(t *testing.T) {
    var hasPanicked bool
    defer func() {
        _ = recover() // if you capture the output value or recover, you get the error gave to the panic call. We have no use of it.
        hasPanicked = true
    }()

    c := fakeGetter{
        err: fmt.Errorf("whatever error will do"),
    }

    resp := sendRequest(c)
    if resp != nil {
        t.Fatal("it should return a nil response when an error arises")
    }
    if !hasPanicked {
        t.Fatal("it should have panicked")
    }
}
```

We can now move on to the other execution path, the non error return.

For that we forge the desired [*http.Response](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Response) instance we want to pass into our function, we will then check its properties to figure out if what the function does is inline with what we expect.

We will consider we want to ensure it is returned unmodified : /

Below test only sets two properties, and I will do it to demonstrate how to set the Body with a [NopCloser](https://pkg.go.dev/io/ioutil#NopCloser) and [strings.NewReader](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#NewReader) as it is often needed later on using the Go language;

I also use [reflect.DeepEqual](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#DeepEqual) as brute force equality checker, usually you can be more fine grained and get better tests. `DeepEqual` does the job in this case but it introduces complexity that does not justify systematic use of it.

```golang
func TestSendRequestReturnsUnmodifiedResponse(t *testing.T) {

    c := fakeGetter{
        err: nil,
        resp: &http.Response{
            Status: http.StatusOK,
            Body:   ioutil.NopCloser(strings.NewReader("some text")),
        },
    }

    resp := sendRequest(c)
    if !reflect.DeepEqual(resp, c.resp) {
        t.Fatal("the response should not have been modified")
    }
}
```

At that point you may have figured that this small function `sendRequest` is not good, if you did not I ensure you it is not. It does too little, it merely wraps the `http.Get` method and its testing is of little interest for the **survival of the business logic**.

Moving on to `readBody` function.

All remarks that applied for `sendRequest` apply here too.

- it does too little
- it `os.Exit`s

One thing does not apply. As the call to `ioutil.ReadAll` does not rely on external resources, there is no point in attempting to inject that dependency. We can test around.

Though, for the sake of the demonstration, it is the time to talk about the missing call to `defer resp.Body.Close()`.

Let us assume we go for the second proposition made in introduction and test for that.

The `http.Response` struct **adequately** exposes its `Body` recipient as an [interface](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#interfaces_and_types).

To ensure the code calls for the `Close, we can write a stub for it.
That stub will record if that call was made, the test can then check for that and trigger an error if it was not.

```golang
type closeCallRecorder struct {
    hasClosed bool
}

func (c *closeCallRecorder) Close() error {
    c.hasClosed = true
    return nil
}
func (c *closeCallRecorder) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
    return 0, nil
}

func TestReadBodyCallsClose(t *testing.T) {

    body := &closeCallRecorder{}
    res := &http.Response{
        Body: body,
    }

    _ = readBody(res)
    if !body.hasClosed {
        t.Fatal("the response body was not closed")
    }
}
```

Similarly, and for the sake of the demonstration, we might want to test if the function has called for `Read`.

```golang
type readCallRecorder struct {
    hasRead bool
}

func (c *readCallRecorder) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
    c.hasRead = true
    return 0, nil
}

func TestReadBodyHasReadAnything(t *testing.T) {

    body := &readCallRecorder{}
    res := &http.Response{
        Body: ioutil.NopCloser(body),
    }

    _ = readBody(res)
    if !body.hasRead {
        t.Fatal("the response body was not read")
    }
}
```

We an also verify the body was not modified in betwen,

```golang
func TestReadBodyDidNotModifyTheResponse(t *testing.T) {
    want := "this"
    res := &http.Response{
        Body: ioutil.NopCloser(strings.NewReader(want)),
    }

    resp := readBody(res)
    if got := string(resp); want != got {
        t.Fatal("invalid response, wanted=%q got %q", want, got)
    }
}
```

We have almost done, lets move one to the `unmarshallData` function.

You have already wrote a test about it. It is okish, though, i would write it this way to make it leaner:

```golang
type UserData struct {
    Meta interface{} `json:"meta"`
    Data Data        `json:"data"`
}
type Data struct {
    ID     int    `json:"id"`
    Name   string `json:"name"`
    Email  string `json:"email"`
    Gender string `json:"gender"`
    Status string `json:"status"`
}

func Test_unmarshallData(t *testing.T) {
    type args struct {
        body []byte
    }
    tests := []UserData{
        UserData{Data: Data{ID: 1841}},
    }
    for _, u := range tests {
        want := u.ID
        b, _ := json.Marshal(u)
        t.Run("Unmarshal", func(t *testing.T) {
            if got := unmarshallData(b); got != want {
                t.Errorf("unmarshallData() = %v, want %v", got, want)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Then, the usual apply :

- don't log.Fatal
- what are you testing ? the marshaller ?

Finally, now that we have gathered all those pieces, we can refactor to write a more sensible function and re use all those pieces to help us testing such code.

I won't do it, but here is a starter, which still panics, and I still don't recommend, but the previous demonstration has shown everything needed to test a version of it that returns an error.

```golang
type userFetcher struct {
    Requester interface {
        Get(u string) (*http.Response, error)
    }
}

func (u userFetcher) Fetch() int {
    resp, err := u.Requester.Get("https://gorest.co.in/public/v1/users/1841") // it does not really matter that this string is static, using the requester we can mock the response, its body and the error.
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close() //always.
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    var userData UserData
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &userData)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return userData.Data.ID
}
```